# Updating multiple pivot tables on another worksheet from another worksheet source

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, pivot-table

I have a schedule that is in another worksheet, not workbook, and have pivot tables updated off that data.

The catch is... when I try to use the macro below, i get a

> Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range.

P.s. >>> The "Schedule 02-26" changes according to date every day.

```
Sub Change_Pivot_Source()

Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Schedule 02-26").PivotTables
pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Schedule!$A$1:$AK$1200")

Next pt

End Sub
```

Easy Fix?

UPDATE: "CAN'T EXECUTE CODE IN BREAK MODE"???

I put the macro code in "This Workbook"

Answer (score 0):

```
'This might be helpful, starting out on your pivot table sheet

 Sub PivotUpdate()

 Dim PivotSheet as string
 Dim Data As Range
 Dim lrow As Long
 Dim PivotCount As Long
 Dim i As Long

 PivotSheet = activesheet.name

 sheets("schedule").select

 'get the last row where your data is
 lrow = sheets("schedule").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

 Set Data = sheets("schedule").Range("A1:AK" & lrow & "")

 Sheets(PivotSheet).Select

  PivotCount = Sheets(PivotSheet).PivotTables.Count

 For i = 1 To PivotCount

     Sheets(PivotSheet).PivotTables(i).ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
     PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Data, _
     Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)

  'version12 is excel 2007

 Next i

 End Sub
```